# see newest release last (YML release files with the same timestamp from Git)

Tags: shell, ls, sort

I pull from Git *yml files with "$packagename-$release.yml". The highest number is the most recent release.

I wish to have the listening with latest release last. Correct sort order "$packagename-$release.yml".

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 pmadm pmadm      3894 Jan 22 19:47 lemmix-9.yml
-rw-r--r--. 1 pmadm pmadm      4074 Jan 22 19:47 lemmix-96.yml
-rw-r--r--. 1 pmadm pmadm      4245 Jan 22 19:47 lemmix-95.yml
-rw-r--r--. 1 pmadm pmadm      4245 Jan 22 19:47 lemmix-94.yml
-rw-r--r--. 1 pmadm pmadm      4245 Jan 22 19:47 lemmix-93.yml
-rw-r--r--. 1 pmadm pmadm      4245 Jan 22 19:47 lemmix-92.yml
-rw-r--r--. 1 pmadm pmadm      4245 Jan 22 19:47 lemmix-91.yml
-rw-r--r--. 1 pmadm pmadm      4245 Jan 22 19:47 lemmix-90.yml
-rw-r--r--. 1 pmadm pmadm      6291 Jan 22 19:47 lemmix-89.yml
-rw-r--r--. 1 pmadm pmadm      6291 Jan 22 19:47 lemmix-88.yml
-rw-r--r--. 1 pmadm pmadm      6291 Jan 22 19:47 lemmix-87.yml
-rw-r--r--. 1 pmadm pmadm      6291 Jan 22 19:47 lemmix-86.yml
-rw-r--r--. 1 pmadm pmadm      4245 Jan 22 19:47 lemmix-99.yml
-rw-r--r--. 1 pmadm pmadm      4245 Jan 22 19:47 lemmix-98.yml
-rw-r--r--. 1 pmadm pmadm      4245 Jan 22 19:47 lemmix-97.yml
-rw-rw-r--. 1 pmadm pmadm      4246 Apr 13 15:35 lemmix-140.yml
-rw-rw-r--. 1 pmadm pmadm      4246 Apr 13 15:35 lemmix-139.yml
-rw-rw-r--. 1 pmadm pmadm      4246 Apr 13 15:35 lemmix-138.yml
-rw-rw-r--. 1 pmadm pmadm      4246 Apr 13 15:35 lemmix-137.yml
-rw-rw-r--. 1 pmadm pmadm      6106 Apr 13 15:35 lemmix-136.yml
-rw-rw-r--. 1 pmadm pmadm      4246 Apr 13 15:35 lemmix-152.yml
-rw-rw-r--. 1 pmadm pmadm      4246 Apr 13 15:35 lemmix-151.yml
-rw-rw-r--. 1 pmadm pmadm      4246 Apr 13 15:35 lemmix-150.yml
-rw-rw-r--. 1 pmadm pmadm      4246 Apr 13 15:35 lemmix-149.yml
-rw-rw-r--. 1 pmadm pmadm      4246 Apr 13 15:35 lemmix-148.yml
-rw-rw-r--. 1 pmadm pmadm      4246 Apr 13 15:35 lemmix-147.yml
-rw-rw-r--. 1 pmadm pmadm      4246 Apr 13 15:35 lemmix-146.yml
-rw-rw-r--. 1 pmadm pmadm      4246 Apr 13 15:35 lemmix-145.yml
-rw-rw-r--. 1 pmadm pmadm      4246 Apr 13 15:35 lemmix-144.yml
-rw-rw-r--. 1 pmadm pmadm      4248 Apr 13 15:35 lemmix-143.yml
-rw-rw-r--. 1 pmadm pmadm      4246 Apr 13 15:35 lemmix-142.yml
-rw-rw-r--. 1 pmadm pmadm      4246 Apr 13 15:35 lemmix-141.yml
-rw-rw-r--. 1 pmadm pmadm      4246 Apr 13 15:35 lemmix-156.yml
-rw-rw-r--. 1 pmadm pmadm      4246 Apr 13 15:35 lemmix-155.yml
-rw-rw-r--. 1 pmadm pmadm      4246 Apr 13 15:35 lemmix-154.yml
-rw-rw-r--. 1 pmadm pmadm      4246 Apr 13 15:35 lemmix-153.yml
-rw-rw-r--. 1 pmadm pmadm      4246 May 26 22:51 lemmix-158.yml
-rw-rw-r--. 1 pmadm pmadm      4246 May 26 22:51 lemmix-157.yml
-rw-rw-r--. 1 pmadm pmadm      4246 May 26 22:51 lemmix-168.yml
-rw-rw-r--. 1 pmadm pmadm      4246 May 26 22:51 lemmix-167.yml
-rw-rw-r--. 1 pmadm pmadm      4246 May 26 22:51 lemmix-166.yml
-rw-rw-r--. 1 pmadm pmadm      4246 May 26 22:51 lemmix-165.yml
-rw-rw-r--. 1 pmadm pmadm      4246 May 26 22:51 lemmix-164.yml
-rw-rw-r--. 1 pmadm pmadm      4246 May 26 22:51 lemmix-163.yml
-rw-rw-r--. 1 pmadm pmadm      4246 May 26 22:51 lemmix-162.yml
-rw-rw-r--. 1 pmadm pmadm      4246 May 26 22:51 lemmix-161.yml
-rw-rw-r--. 1 pmadm pmadm      4246 May 26 22:51 lemmix-160.yml
-rw-rw-r--. 1 pmadm pmadm      4246 May 26 22:51 lemmix-159.yml
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a `ls(1)` from GNU `coreutils`:

```
ls -lv lemmix-*
```

Alternatively, with GNU `sort(1)`:

```
ls -l lemmix-* | sort -k9 -V
```

Comment: thanks "-v     natural sort of (version) numbers within text"

Comment: @fyodor78 Please note the upper case `-V` for `sort(1)`